# Different size between Canvas and Container SigmaJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, graphics, sigma.js

I'm getting this error when I load my graph.
I'm using a small graph just with 2 nodes and 1 link in between. The canvas area reload properly but the other one keeps frozen after any change.
What is displayed is the labels frozen on the container
[Only the inside area is refreshed propperly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55RR3.png)

As You can see there is a different height and width between the canvas and the Container that wrap it.
[Here is the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDEyC.png)

Answer (score 1):

I get it, it's solved using a custom renderer.

```
renderer: {container: document.getElementById('sigma-container'), type: 'canvas'},
```